# Need suggestion to fix website load time issue

Tags: php, apache, nginx, vps, sentora

I want some suggestion to fix site speed problem i am using `Apache` and `nginx` need some configuration to fix load time issue
My `VPS` specification

```
> 30GB Ram
> 2000 GB SSD-boosted
> 1 Gbit/s port UNLIMITED Traffic
> UP steam 120 Gbit/s
> Six cores Processor
```

I am using `sentora(zadmin)` web panel i am facing too much load time issue my server response is good but page take too much time to load i thing there is problem with my web panel configuration.

PING DATA

```
---   DIRECT SERVER IP DATA   ---
Pinging 173.212.213.220 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 173.212.213.220: bytes=32 time=279ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.212.213.220: bytes=32 time=277ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.212.213.220: bytes=32 time=278ms TTL=47
Reply from 173.212.213.220: bytes=32 time=278ms TTL=47

Ping statistics for 173.212.213.220:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 277ms, Maximum = 279ms, Average = 278ms

   --- IP BIND BY CLOUDFLARE ---
Reply from 104.18.60.166: bytes=32 time=147ms TTL=52
Reply from 104.18.60.166: bytes=32 time=147ms TTL=52
Reply from 104.18.60.166: bytes=32 time=147ms TTL=52
Reply from 104.18.60.166: bytes=32 time=146ms TTL=52

Ping statistics for 104.18.60.166:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 146ms, Maximum = 147ms, Average = 146ms
```

Server running on Cantos 6.9

> Updated

error log

```
[Tue Jun 19 07:53:58 2018] [error] child process 4442 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Tue Jun 19 07:53:59 2018] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jun 19 07:54:00 2018] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Jun 19 07:54:00 2018] [notice] Digest: done
```

Apache httpd.conf

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       16
MinSpareServers    10
MaxSpareServers   40
ServerLimit      1024
MaxClients       1024
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Most of the information you have presented here is irrelevant to the problem. The information required to support an informed decision about the next steps is way beyond the scope of a question here.

Comment: Tell me what i need to do? I do google search nothing found related to my problem

Comment: Read a lot. Steve Souder's "High Performance websites" is very good (and you should start your investigation at the browser end) I'd like to think my book - "linux. Apache, MySQL and PHP Performance End to End" (C. McKinnon) is also. Both are available from Amazon. Stoyan Stefanov's Perfplanet website has some useful posts - although its a bit more piecemeal than the books.